# How to rotate hexagon follow the edge using css3/canvas

Tags: jquery, css, canvas

I want rotate hexagon but don't know how...

[image]

I appreciate you helping me!

Comment: i dont think its rotation.. its z-index and less width effect..

Comment: Sympathy for me, I do not know how it's expressed... You have solution solve my problem?

Comment: can you please paste the code to create the hexagon? then i will try

Comment: i mean i just want to know u r using jquery to desing hexagon or pure css3

Comment: You can experiment with CSS transformations to achieve this effect - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform

Comment: @UserNaN I have posted my answer with jsfiddle sample check it out..

Comment: Thanks for reply! I only use the images (I don't have code), I want to rotating the image same with my example

Answer (score 1):

This is actually done with scaling rather than rotating.

If you start with this image:

[image]

And then scale its width to 50% of its original width, you get this:

[image]

Here's code on how to scale the width to 50%:

```
// move the canvas origin(0,0) to the center of the canvas

ctx.translate(canvas.width/2,canvas.height/2);

// scale the width to 50% of its original width

ctx.scale(0.50,1);

// finally draw the image, which will be scaled in width

ctx.drawImage(img,-img.width/2,-img.height/2);
```

So to create your effect:

- scale the orange and purple hexagons to 50% width
- draw them close to each other
- draw the gold hexagon on top of the other 2 hexagons

Answer (score 1):

I asked u you are using pure CSS3 or jquery you didnt replay..

I am considering u r using pure css3 check it

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UQpML/2/)

[image: output would be ..]

HTML code is -

```
<div class="hexagon-small" id="first"></div>
<div class="hexagon-big" id="second"></div>
<div class="hexagon-small" id="third"></div>
```

and its the CSS

```
#first
{
    left:0px;
}
#second
{
    left:-53px;    
}

#third
{
    left:-106px;
}
.hexagon-small {
    width: 50px;
    height: 55px;
    background: black;
    position: relative;
    display:inline-block;
    top:25px;
    z-index:50;
}
.hexagon-small:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: -25px;
    left: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 25px solid transparent;
    border-right: 25px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 25px solid black;
}
.hexagon-small:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -25px;
    left: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 25px solid transparent;
    border-right: 25px solid transparent;
    border-top: 25px solid black;
}


.hexagon-big {
    width: 100px;
    height: 55px;
    background: red;
    position: relative;
    display:inline-block;
    top:25px;
    z-index:100;
}
.hexagon-big:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: -25px;
    left: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 25px solid red;
}
.hexagon-big:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -25px;
    left: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    border-top: 25px solid red;
}
```

Comment: ur welcome. dont forget to mark it as answer so that other can find it helpful.